# Binding Local Dataset To Reportviewer In ASP.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind dataset's data to ReportViewer object , I create rdlc report and set it as ReportViewer's report source in design view , but it doesn't show anything ,I checked dataset's data by binding gridview and it's work and show the data in gridview but in ReportViewer object doesn't , Please Help . Here is the code:1(Note: "Temp" is the table's Name of database , that's i want to bind to ReportViewer)2(I don't want to use xsd dataset item)

```
string path = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated      Security=True";

 SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(path);
 con1.Open();
 const string query = "select * From [Table1] where date between @from and @to";
 SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
 com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", DateTime.Parse(r1));
 com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", DateTime.Parse(r2));
 SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
 DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
 adp1.Fill(ds1);
 com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con1.Close();


 GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
 GridView1.DataBind();

 ReportViewer1.Reset();
 ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Temp",  ds1.Tables[0]));

 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so, you also need to add  controls like textboxes or tables to the report and create expressions that reference the fields in the dataset. For example, you could click on the Toolbox in visual studio, and drag a textbox to the report designer. Then right click the textbox, and choose Expression. When the Expression dialog box appears, look in the Category section for Fields(nameofYourDataset), click it, and look in the Values section for the names of fields from your dataset. Double click one of them which will populate the top section, and click OK.